# Android: Layouts "slide" off the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a layout much like the one below. Currently when the back button is pressed the red linear layout's visibility is set to gone. However, I'd like it to "slide" up off of the page instead. How would I do this?

[image: my layout]

Comment: why don't you try using animation for this purpose. As, I don't think there could be anyother way or method defined for slide off

Comment: How would I use animation to achieve this? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: you want one layout slideoff and another layout should come as visible.......Am I understanding right

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use animations. here is the top in/out animations:

In Top

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%" android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

Out Top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-100%" android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

Then in your activity get the view and apply an animation to it like this:
This are type Animation.

```
  mSlideInTop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_top);
        mSlideOutTop = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out_top);
```

and call them with this code:

```
header.startAnimation(mSlideOutTop);
        header.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Here header is a LinearLayout wrapping my views. same thing if you want to make it slide in. just add the slide in animation and make the view visible.

Comment: Where is mSlideInTop defined? And should I put that under the onCreate() method? And where do I define which XML file should it slide in/out?

Comment: It depends on your needs. You usually create the animation object just before you actually start it but i guess it might be a field initialized in the activity inside onCreate. The XML goes under res/anim folder.

Comment: it dose not work in my app. the view on the top just disapeared and no animation happend. what I did is: 1: titleHideAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.anim_top_out_slow);   2:        titleLayout.startAnimation(titleHideAnimation);   3:         titleLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: Any ideas on why the duration for Out is doubled than the one for In, but visually feels the same?